# Cannot Convert from OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement to Open.Qa.Selenium.By

Tags: c#, selenium

I have been working on making my Selenium Framework a Page Factory, however i am struggling to get the Wait.Until commands working in my Extension Class.

```
public static void Wait(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver, float TimeOut)
{
    WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOut));
    return Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
}
```

If I use the above code I get the error 
Cannot Convert from OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement to Open.Qa.Selenium.By

Any suggestions how can I amend the code above to make it work in the By model I am using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is no `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(IWebElement)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm). Unfortunately, you can only use `ElementIsVisible` with `By` objects.

If appropriate, you could [substitute with `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(IWebElement)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm), which is a slightly different case that also checks that the element is enabled in addition to being visible. But this may satisfy your requirement.

Alternatively, you could just call `element.Displayed` in a custom `WebDriverWait`, making sure to ignore or catch the `NoElementException`

Here is an old implementation of this I've used and changed for your case, there may be a cleaner way to do it now:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOut))
{
    Message = "Element was not displayed within timeout of " + TimeOut + " seconds"
}.Until(d => 
{
    try
    {
        return element.Displayed;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A quick explanation for the code above... It will try to execute `element.Displayed` over and over until it returns `true`. When the `element` does not exist, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` which will return `false` so the `WebDriverWait` will continue to execute until both the `element` exists, and `element.Displayed` returns true, or the `TimeOut` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
```

with the below line of code and check, as this worked for me

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("ctlLogin_UserName")));
```

wherein `"ctlLogin_UserName"` is the ID of your web element.